# Proving a Definite Integral Inequality without Geometrical Intuition

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

I solved an integral inequality problem using geometrical methods. However, I just cannot satisfy with them and want a without-geometrical-intuition proof, and I couldn't find one.

Proof the following inequality holds when $a>0, b>0$
$$\int_{0}^{a}{\ln(x+1)\mathrm{dx}}+\int_{0}^{b}{(e^x-1)\mathrm{dx}}\geqslant ab$$

I would prefer a solution which does not involve actually solving the integral, but any proof without geometry would be a big help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just for reference (as this technique could be used to prove e.g., [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions)), the "geometric intuition" referred by OP is presumably the following:

consider a continuous monotonic increasing function $y=f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function of $f$, then $\int_0^af(x)~dx$ is the area under the curve and $\int_0^bf^{-1}(y)~dy$ is the area above the curve. (cont.)

Comment: The union of these two areas cover the rectangle $[0,a]\times[0,b]$, which results

$$\int_0^af(x)~dx+\int_0^bf^{-1}(y)~dy\ge ab.$$

Assume $f(a)\ge b$ (switch $x$ and $y$ otherwise), the difference between LHS and RHS is

$$\int_{f^{-1}(b)}^a (f(x)-b)~dx\ge 0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both these are straightforward integrals. The first is

$$((x+1)\ln(x+1)-x)\bracevert_0^a=(a+1)\ln(a+1)-a$$ and the second is $$(e^x-x)\bracevert_0^b=e^b-b-1$$

Let us put $b=ka$. Then we have to show that for all $a>0,k>0$ we have $$f(a,k)=(a+1)\ln(a+1)-a+e^{ka}-ka-1-ka^2\ge0$$
Differentiating wrt $k$, we get $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}=a(e^{ka}-1-a)$$ Putting $k_a=\frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}$, we see that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}$ is $<0,=0,>0$ according as for $k<k_a,k=k_a,k>k_a$. So we have a minimum at $k=k_a$. We have $$f(a,k_a)=(a+1)\ln(a+1)-a+(1+a)-\ln(1+a)-1-a\ln(1+a)=0$$ This result holds for all $a>0$ so the result is established.

$\textbf{Comment}$

At first sight this is an irritating result, because it seems really weak. The exponential will surely swamp everything else, except maybe for small $b$. Then it turns out to be much harder to prove than expected. The argument above shows that for any $a$ you can find a $b$ which gives equality and vice versa, so the result is not as weak as it looks.

For example, if we take $a=1$, then $k_a=\ln2$, so the corresponding $b=\ln2\approx0.6931$ and $\int_0^1\ln(x+1)\ dx=2\ln2-1$ and $\int_0^{\ln2}e^x-1\ dx=1-\ln2$. So their sum is $\ln2=ab$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [almagest](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/172006/almagest), I illegitimately disregard one term. As it is right now, this is not a proof.

Notice that for all $x\geqslant 0$, one has the following inequalities: $$\begin{align}\ln(x+1)&\geqslant x-\frac{x^2}{2}\\e^x&\geqslant x-1\end{align}.$$
Therefore, one gets: $$\int_0^a\ln(x+1)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^b(e^x-1)\,\mathrm{d}x\geqslant\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-\frac{a^3}{6}\geqslant\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}.$$
Besides, since $(a-b)^2\geqslant 0$, one has: $a^2+b^2\geqslant 2ab$. Whence, the result.

Comment: Why do you disregard the $\frac{a^3}{6}$?

Comment: Some really bad job on my part, I mixed up inequalites in my head. As it is right now my proof is totally false!

Comment: But with some good ideas ...

Comment: The snag is that if you do the log integral explicitly you get $(a+1)\ln(a+1)-a$ which is *less* than $\frac{1}{2}a^2$ for all positive $a$. So aiming to prove that the sum is greater than $(a^2+b^2)/2$ is hopeless, because that is not true for sufficiently small $b$.

Comment: That is exactly what I was starting to think when computing explicitly the integral. Maybe one cannot avoid the computations to solve this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$f(a,b):=\int_0^a\log(1+x)\>dx+\int_0^b(e^x-1)\>dx$$
grows without bounds when $a\to\infty$ or $b\to\infty$. It therefore assumes a global minimum under the constraints $$a>0,\quad b>0,\qquad ab=M$$
for given $M>0$, and this minimum will be brought to the fore by Lagrange's method. We obtain the equations
$$\log(1+a)-\lambda b=0,\qquad e^b-1-\lambda a=0,$$
which immediately lead to
$$a\log(1+a)=b(e^b-1)\ .\tag{1}$$
Given $a>0$ one easily guesses that $b=\log(1+a)$ solves $(1)$, and since the right hand side of $(1)$ is monotone for $b>0$ this is the only solution. The condition $ab=M$ then determines $a$ via $a\log(1+a)=M$. Call the pair of values so obtained $(a_M,b_M)$.

Now let arbitrary $a>0$, $b>0$ be given, and put $ab=:M$. Then
$$f(a,b)\geq f(a_M,b_M)=\ldots=a_M\log(1+a_M)=M=ab\ .$$